# How to connect to a docker server on the network set-up with Hyper-V

Tags: networking, docker, hyper-v, docker-machine

Basically my question is: How do I connect to a docker host on the network?

**Background:**

We have a Windows Server 2012 machine that I would like to run a docker engine from.

I've managed to get it running with docker-machine and the hyperv driver. I've also successfully gotten a docker host to work on my computer locally using VirtualBox, and have been using it.

To ease access to docker for other people on the network on a perpetual set-up, I'd like to use the docker host instance on the server with Hyper-V.

In my search for answers, I've not been able to find any mention of provisioning hosts on the network, only on the local and cloud.

I'd like to know what commands do I have to use to connect my local docker-machine to the server's docker host, and use it as the active docker host?

Comment: how did you get docker for windows working on server 2012?  I thought it was going to be a 2016 server thing?  Also, how can you be running virtualbox and hyper-v at the same time, I thought that conflicts?  I would prefer to run virtualbox on my 2012 server, but I have a hyperv running an environment with all of the SQL SSRS etc for us.

Comment: @ivan7707 This isn't actually docker for Windows, but just the linux-based boot2docker image that one would have used to install on VirtualBox. In this situation I have it installed on Hyper-V instead of VirtualBox on a remote server, and I connect to/use it from another Windows computer with docker-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a blog post explaining how to add a docker engine with an IP with the generic driver, as well as some extra steps you need to go through.

[ADDING AN EXISTING DOCKER HOST TO DOCKER MACHINE : A FEW TIPS](https://blog.dahanne.net/2015/10/07/adding-an-existing-docker-host-to-docker-machine-a-few-tips)

---

**SSH Keys**

The bottom section on certs explains how to get working on the remote docker engine after connecting with the `create` command

**Old answer**

To create/connect successfully the local machine must be able to ssh into the remote docker engine, and not just the server hosting the docker engine. This means a public key was generated and added (using puttygen or ssh-keygen) on the local machine and the OpenSSH RSA public key was added to the list of authorized keys in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote docker engine.

An example of an OpenSSH RSA public key (because I get confused by these formats):

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBAJ3hB5SAF6mBXPlZlRoJEZi0KSIN+NU2iGiaXZXi9CDrgVxTp6/sc56UcYCp4qjfrZ2G3+6PWbxYso4P4YyUC+61RU5KPy4EcTJske3O+aNvec/20cW7PT3TvH1+sxwGrymD50kTiXDgo5nXdqFvibgM61WW2DGTKlEUsZys0njRAAAAFQDs7ukaTGJlZdeznwFUAttTH9LrwwAAAIAMm4sLCdvvBx9WPkvWDX0OIXSteCYckiQxesOfPvz26FfYxuTG/2dljDlalC+kYG05C1NEcmZWSNESGBGfccSYSfI3Y5ahSVUhOC2LMO3JNjVyYUnOM/iyhzrnRfQoWO9GFMaugq0jBMlhZA4UO26yJqJ+BtXIyItaEEJdc/ghIwAAAIBFeCZynstlbBjP648+mDKIvzNSS+JYr5klGxS3q8A56NPcYhDMxGn7h1DKbb2AV4pO6y+6hDrWo3UT4dLVuzK01trwpPYp6JXTSZZ12ZaXNPz7sX9/z6pzMqhX4UEfjVsLcuF+ZS6aQCPO0ZZEa1z+EEIZSD/ykLQsDwPxGjPBqw= rsa-key-20160224
```

Not having this key in the remote docker engine gave me a `exit status 255` when I attempted to `docker ssh` into it. At this point, only regular `ssh docker@192.168.1.165` worked. Be prepared to repeat the above process.

---

The article also mentions sudo, but the boot2docker image used by the Hyper-V driver already allows password-less sudo so that part is already done.

**Ports**

Make sure TCP port 2376 is allowed connection to the remote docker engine, through the server's firewall rules, physical firewall etc.

**The Command to Run**

Then this command connects the remote engine to docker-machine:

```
> docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address 192.168.1.165 --generic-ssh-user %USERNAME% vm
> docker-machine ls
NAME             ACTIVE      DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM                   DOCKER   ERRORS
default          -           virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376                           v1.10.1
vm               -           generic      Running   tcp://192.168.1.165:2376                            Unknown
```

`vm` is the newly added docker engine from the network, and 192.168.1.165 is the IP of the docker engine on the server.

**Certs**

If this works, just copying over the certs (ca.pem, ca-key.pem, cert.pem, key.pem) from the remote server directory `%USERPROFILE%\.docker\machine\machines\<server's local docker engine name>` to the same location on the local machine should keep it connected. **Do not** use `docker-machine regenerate-certs` since this disables any connections that other computers might have to that docker engine, including the server itself.

**Active**

Then finally making the engine active completes the connection.

```
> IF /F "tokens=*" %G ('docker-machine env vm') do %G
```

---

Note: [This issue](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2518) points out that the command `docker-machine create --driver none --url=tcp://192.168.1.165:2376 <name>` should add a remote machine's docker engine as well, should the "none" driver be working in a future version.